# PHP GAE readdir() doesn't work as intended

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to recursively list every file that is in my bucket. It's not too many files but I'd like to list them to test a few things. This code works on a normal file system but it's not working on Google Cloud Storage.

Anyone have any suggestions?

```
function recurse_look($src) { 
    $dir = opendir($src); 

    while(false !== ( $file = readdir($dir)) ) { 
        if (( $file != '.' ) && ( $file != '..' )) { 
            if ( is_dir($src . '/' . $file) ) { 
                recurse_look($src . '/' . $file); 
            } 
            else { 
                echo $src . '/' . $file;
                echo "<br />";
            } 
        } 
    } 
    closedir($dir); 
} 

recurse_look("gs://<BUCKET>");
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: No errors. It only lists selective folders and zero files. @Barett

Comment: I had to do `$file = rtrim($file, "/");` because it was adding a random `/` to the end for no reason

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would recommend not using a filesystem-impersonation abstraction layer on top of Google Cloud Storage, for a task such as listing everything inside a bucket -- rather, just reach out for the underlying functionality.

In particular, see https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-php-samples for everything about authentication etc, and, once, that's taken care of, focus on just one line in the example:

```
$objects = $storageService->objects->listObjects(DEFAULT_BUCKET);
```

This is all you need to list **all** objects in a bucket (which is **not** the same thing as "files in a directory", and the "filesystem simulations" on top of buckets and objects, I offer as being just my personal opinion, end up hurting rather than helping despite their excellent intentions:-).

Now if the objects' names contain e.g slashes and you want to take that into account as symbolically signifying something or other, go right ahead, but at least this way you're **sure** you're getting **all** the objects actually existing in the bucket, and, nothing but those!-)

Comment: Thanks for the long and thoughtful response. The main reason for using the method I was using was because I needed a one-time solution to get all the files names so that I could re-ACL my files. I'll definitely take this into consideration if I were to look for a long-term approach. With that being said, I didn't have `/` in the folder name, for some reason, GAE is adding them. It may be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Now that glob is working, you can try something like this

```
function lstree($dir) {
  foreach (glob($dir . '/*') as $path) {
  if (is_dir($path)) {
    echo $path;
    lstree($path);
  } else {
    echo $path;
  }
}

lstree('gs://{bucket}/');
```